# Получение размеров файлов с помощью du. Список файлов хранится в текстовом файле. Linux

Tags: linux, консоль

Есть файл a.txt, в котором хранятся имена файлов и каталогов. Мне надо получить размер этих файлов.
Пытался cat a.txt | du -c. Но оно работает не так, как хочется.

Comment: Если файл небольшой, то `cat a.txt | xargs du -c`; если большой, то `cat a.txt | tr '\n' '\0' |  du -c --files0-from=-`

Answer (score 0):

`grep "^[.]*" test.txt|sed 's/ /\\ /g'|xargs du -sh`
и 100500 других методов.